# Is there a replacement for the methods: Drive.getDriveClient(), Drive.getDriveResourceClient, ... from deprecated api?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

Deprecated methods in the code (below) made it possible to integrate the Google Drive Picker into the Android application.

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveClient; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResourceClient; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Metadata; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityOptions; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filters; // deprecated
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.SearchableField; // deprecated

    // ...

    /**
     * Handles high-level drive functions like sync
     */
    private DriveClient mDriveClient; // deprecated
    private Drive mDriveService; // deprecated

    /**
     * Handle access to Drive resources/files.
     */
    private DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient; // deprecated

    // ...

    /**
     * Continues the sign-in process, initializing the Drive clients with the current
     * user's account.
     */
    private void initializeDriveClient(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {
        mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(getApplicationContext(), signInAccount);
        mDriveResourceClient = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getApplicationContext(), signInAccount);
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * Prompts the user to select a folder using OpenFileActivity.
     *
     * @param openOptions Filter that should be applied to the selection
     * @return Task that resolves with the selected item's ID.
     */
    private Task<DriveId> pickItem(OpenFileActivityOptions openOptions) {
        mOpenItemTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
        getDriveClient()
                .newOpenFileActivityIntentSender(openOptions)
                .continueWith((Continuation<IntentSender, Void>) task -> {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                            task.getResult(), REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_ITEM,
                            null, 0, 0, 0);
                    return null;
                });
        return mOpenItemTaskSource.getTask();
    }

    /**
     * Handles resolution callbacks.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_ITEM:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityOptions.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                    mOpenItemTaskSource.setResult(driveId);
                    fileId = driveId.getResourceId();
                } else {
                    mOpenItemTaskSource.setException(
                            new RuntimeException("Unable to open file")
                    );
                }
                break;
                }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * To retrieve the metadata of a file.
     */
    private void retrieveMetadata(final DriveFile file) {
        Task<Metadata> getMetadataTask = getDriveResourceClient().getMetadata(file);
        getMetadataTask
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        (Metadata metadata) -> {
                            showMessage(getString(
                                    R.string.metadata_retrieved, metadata.getTitle()));
                            fileName = metadata.getTitle();
                            sendDownloadAuthData();
                            finish();
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to retrieve metadata", e);
                    showMessage(getString(R.string.read_failed));
                    finish();
                });
    }

    protected DriveResourceClient getDriveResourceClient() {
        return mDriveResourceClient;
    }

    protected DriveClient getDriveClient() {
        return mDriveClient;
    }
```

In the new Drive Api v3, I didn’t find the methods that allow to preserve the functionality of the program. In one of the examples from Google suggests using SAF. But SAF works through android.net.Uri. It allows to get the name of the file, but it does not provide for the file ID.

```
    /**
     * Opens the file at the {@code uri} returned by a Storage Access 
       Framework {@link Intent}
     * created by {@link #createFilePickerIntent()} using the given 
       {@code contentResolver}.
     */
    public Task<String> getCurrentFileName(
            ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri uri) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            // Retrieve the document's display name from its metadata.
            String currentName = "";
            try (Cursor cursor = contentResolver
                    .query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "cursor.getColumnCount(): " + 
                     cursor.getColumnCount());
                    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        Log.d(TAG, i + " - " + cursor.getString(i) + 
                      "\n");
                    }
                    int nameIndex = 
                  cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                    currentName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                } else {
                    throw new IOException("Empty cursor returned for 
               file.");
                }
            }

            return currentName;
        });
    }
```

The file ID is needed for the method:

```
void downloadFile(String fileId) {
        try {
            java.io.File targetFile = new java.io.File(FULL_PATH_MD);
            mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

            mDriveService.files()
                    .export(fileId, "text/csv")
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(mFileOutputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Utils.closeQuietly(mFileOutputStream, true);
        }
    }
```

Additional information to the question on the link:
[How to migrate to Drive API v3 and get file ID for files.export?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416007/how-to-migrate-to-drive-api-v3-and-get-file-id-for-files-export)

What can I replace the deprecated methods to preserve the functionality of the program? What do you advise?

Comment: Have you checked the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation)?

Comment: Yes, this is my handbook last three weeks. From there: "File Picker UI. 
For clients that use the Android API's file picker (e.g. by calling DriveClient#newOpenFileActivityIntentSender), we recommend using Storage Access Framework (SAF) which accesses the Drive Android app's content provider. The sample app demonstrates how to initiate the file picker Intent and process the data it returns."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename file through Uri and then find it and get its file id.

```
public Uri renameFile(ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri uri, String newFilename) {
        Uri newLink = null;
        try {
            newLink = DocumentsContract.renameDocument(context, uri, newFilename);
        } catch (SecurityException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newLink;
    }

    Task<FileList> queryFile(String newFileName) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () ->
                service.files().list()
                    .setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'")
                    .setQ("fullText contains " + "'" + newFileName + "'")
                    .setQ("trashed = false")
                    .setFields("files(id, name)")
                    .execute()
        );
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve some of the problems with the functionality of my application, but you pointed me to a compromise solution. I hope in the near future, Google engineers will insert a File Picker for Android into a new api. Thanks!!!

Comment: Be aware, Tasks.call(mExecutor is deprecated nowadays